# Why aren't {...props} necessary when passing them to a component in a router in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've started learning React recently and when I was following a course I stumbled upon something that confused me a lot. I decided to try it out separately to understand it and I don't get it.

I've looked it up and when you use a Route Tag in React, you do it like this:

```
<Route path="/" component={Component} />
```

But when you want to pass props, the syntax is the following:

```
<Route path='/dashboard' render={(props) => (
    <Dashboard {...props} isAuthed={true} />
  )}
/>
```

Which at first confused me, but then I got it. When testing, I did the following:

```
<Route path="/" render={() => (
  <PropDrilling user={"Someone"} />
)}>
```

When I test this in the component, console.logging `this.props`, it works and I don't know why.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `{...props}` means you are _forwarding_ the props received as a function parameter to a component, irrespective of what the value of `props` is.

Comment: Which means you could be sending empty prop too. - Adding on @AyushGupta

Comment: You are confusing `this.props` inside the component with how those props are created  before it actually gets compiled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React router uses [React's render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) where react router uses [match, location and history](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func). So, when you don't provide `props` in the render function, it will still be able to show you react component props. But it would not include `match, location and history` props provided by react router. To use them, you must provide props parameter in the render function.

Answer (score 0):

Using an analogy, consider

```
function test(obj) {
   console.log(obj);
}
test({a : 1});
```

```
function test() {
   console.log({a : 1});
}
test();
```

These two functions log the same result, but one has no information about the data passed to `console.log`, while the other does.

Similarily, `{...props}` means you are forwarding the props received as a function parameter to a component, irrespective of what the value of `props` is.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the example of `<Route path="/" component={Component} />`, you could write it like that :

```
const myProps = {
path: "/",
component: <YourComponent />
}

<Route {...myProps} />
```

Consider every props passed to a component as a key in an object. Here is [a small repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-5mffd5) to show you how it works.